# Convert Binary Hex representation to string keeping same output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Server query

```
DECLARE @StartRange BINARY(8)
DECLARE @EndRange BINARY(8)

SET @StartRange = 0x0000004A50F119B
SET @EndRange = 0x00000004A50F11FF 

SELECT 
    CONVERT(BINARY(6), RW + CONVERT(INTEGER, @StartRange))
FROM
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.id) AS RW 
     FROM
         syscolumns, syscolumns a, syscolumns b, syscolumns c) b
WHERE
     RW BETWEEN 1 AND (CONVERT(INTEGER, @EndRange) - CONVERT(INTEGER, @StartRange))
```

This generates 100 records like following one:

```
0xFFFFA50F119C
```

What I need is to convert the hex binary representation to string so I can remove the 0x value and just keep the next 12 characters. So what I need is to get something like this:

```
FFFFA50F119C
```

If I do a cast or convert it will try to convert that into ASCII characters and that's not what I need.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convert` to a string then use `substring` to remove the `0x`. [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has a special style for converting binary data to a string represented in hex.

```
substring(convert(varchar(12),CONVERT(BINARY(6), RW + CONVERT(INTEGER, @StartRange)),2/*Binary convert style*/),3,10)
```